# Does Localstack support AWS Lambda layers

Tags: aws-lambda, localstack

Does Localstack support AWS Lambda layers? Now, I can only see the S3 bucket created for this.

Comment: As I can see no support. Trying to make serverless + layers to work with Localstack, but most of the things aren't working.

Answer (score 1):

So far, lambda layers are part of localstack pro version

Source: https://github.com/localstack/localstack#overview